# How do I remove duplicate numbers?

Tags: php

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="values" value="1,2,1,3,4,2,2,5" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['values']))
{
    $values = $_POST['values']); //remove duplicate numbers

    echo $values;
}
```

**Output**

1,2,3,4,5

How would that work? First sort the numbers? And then run them through a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intution is correct: You'd sort and then loop.

But PHP already has built-ins that do all the work for you. Like this:

```
array_unique(explode(',', $_POST['values']));
```

and if you need a string again, use implode:

```
implode(',', array_unique(explode(',', $_POST['values'])));
```

- http://www.php.net/array_unique
- http://www.php.net/explode
- http://www.php.net/implode

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). Explode $values with comma, to get the array, then call array_unique.

```
<?php

$values = explode(',', $_POST['values']);
var_dump(array_unique($values));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$values = '6,5,4,1,2,1,3,4,2,2,5';
$values = explode(',', $values);
$values = array_unique($values);
sort($values);
$values = implode(',', $values);
// $values = 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow Steps:

- First [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) string to array using `,` as separator.
- Delete duplicate values using [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)
- [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) back array into string

**Example:**

```
$values = "1,2,1,3,4,2,2,5";
echo implode( ',' , array_unique( explode( ',', $values) ) );
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/9thrv)

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=array_unique(explode(',',$_POST['values']));    
$values=implode(',',$array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
if(isset($_POST['values']))
{
    $values = $_POST['values']); 
    //remove duplicate numbers
    $values = explode(',', $values);
    $values = array_unique($values);
    $values = implode(',', $values);

    echo $values;
}
```